# ASP.net Menu - How to change Pop out Image on Hover

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a Pop out image setup in an ASP.net menu for menu items that have a child drop down menu. The problem is a i want to be able to have that image change on hover and not sure if i can do it through CSS or C#.

Menu item with arrow image: [image]

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" StaticPopOutImageUrl="~/Sites/0/PageLayouts/Images/Horizontal_Main_Arrow.jpg" ItemWrap="false" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
<DataBindings>
    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" TextField="Title" NavigateUrlField="URL" />
</DataBindings>
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="TopStaticMenuStyle" />
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="TopStaticSelectedStyle" />
<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="TopStaticMenuItemStyle" />
<DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="TopDynamicHoverStyle" />
<DynamicMenuStyle  CssClass="TopDynamicMenuStyle" />
<DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="TopDynamicSelectedStyle" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="TopDynamicMenuItemStyle" />
<StaticHoverStyle CssClass="TopStaticHoverStyle" />
```

Page Source:

```
<td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)"
    onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)"
    onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)"
    id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Menu1n1">
  <table class="TopStaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Menu1_4"
         cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <a class="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Menu1_1 TopStaticMenuItemStyle ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Menu1_3"
           href="Home.aspx" target="_self"
           style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;"
         >Our Expertise</a>
      </td>
      <td style="width:0;">
        <img src="../Sites/0/PageLayouts/Images/Horizontal_Main_Arrow.jpg"
             alt="Expand Our Expertise"
             style="border-style:none;vertical-align:middle;" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Javascript - just add the following attributes to your img tag:

> onmouseover="this.src='../Sites/0/PageLayouts/Images/Horizontal_Main_Arrow_Highlighted.jpg';"
>
> onmouseout="this.src='../Sites/0/PageLayouts/Images/Horizontal_Main_Arrow.jpg';"

(or whatever your other jpg is!)

Comment: That's the problem, The IMG html tag is created dynamically by the asp.net menu control. It is set in the ASPX code above. I dont have access to give it an ID or change the tag. That's where my problem is. Thanks though.

Comment: Hmm, so it's a third party control you're using? Maybe you could use jQuery to hook into the img tag and add the attributes?

Comment: it's the asp.net menu control. i might have to lookup using jQuery to do it.